# How to avoid pre filled form values in password and email textfields

Tags: php, html, cookies

I have both login and a registration form in my page. When i save my login credentials(email and password) in browser, the next time when i open the site, the login credentials as well as the fields(email and password) in my registration form gets auto filled. I want to avoid auto filling in registration form only.

I guess it may be of cookies but i don't know anything about cookies. Can any one help me please?

Please find my code for registration and login form

Email should be in a format

                                         
                                          
                                          


                              




                                 
                                        


                                       
                                        
                                        


                            Fresher         
                                    Experienced                                 
                            

                                     Select you status
                              
                                      

                            Register

```
 <div id="log"><!--............Login Form.............................-->
                <form action="" method="POST" autocomplete="off" id="form1">
                  <input type="text" name="email_id" id="email_id3" placeholder="Email or Phone number" ">
                  <input type="Password" name="passwrd" id="passwrd3" placeholder="Password" >                    
                   </br>
                  <button type="submit" name="sub1" id="login" class="">login</button>
                  <div id="wrng01"></div><div id="wrng"></div>
                </form>
     </div>
```

Comment: It's browser dependant. Nothing to do with php.

Comment: Please post the appropriate html code

Comment: go to your browser's setting and clear the auto complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, as at this point in time you haven't added the appropriate code, but is the same name and or id associated with both the login and registration form?

#### Is this the case?

**registration**

`<input type="email" name="email">`

**login**

`<input type="email" name="email">`

If so, try this:

**registration**

`<input type="email" name="registration-email">`

**login**

`<input type="email" name="login-email">`

just make sure to update your php code to match the post variables.

---

Or to disable autocomplete outright,

add `autocomplete="off"` to the appropriate inputs

like this: `<input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="off">`